# Sending Keypress Enter by Javascript does not trigger form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert some jQuery script to a website that has keyword searching.
For example, when I insert below code into amazon.com in order to set a keyword,and send enter keypress by jQuery, the form is not submitted. What prevents the form to be submitted? What is different from actually pressing enter key on my keyboard?

```
var $searchbox = $('#twotabsearchtextbox');// this is search box element
$searchbox.keypress(function(event){
  if ((event.keyCode) == 13) {
    alert('keypress triggered');
  }
});

$searchbox.val('test keyword');
var e = $.Event('keypress', {which: 13, keyCode: 13, charCode: 13});
$searchbox.trigger(e);
```

Comment: it's normal, it's a matter of safety

Comment: Thank you. So for a security reason, even if a textbox received enter keypress event, it won't submit the the wrapping form? If I directly manipulate the wrapping form, the form is submitted.

Comment: The safety principle  is that only a human being (and not a machine) can voluntarily send any information (entered by himself) to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

```js
var $searchbox = $('#twotabsearchtextbox');// this is search box element
$searchbox.val('test keyword');
$searchbox.keypress(function(event){
  if ((event.keyCode) == 13) {
    alert('keypress triggered');
  }
});

 $("button").click(function(){
    var e = $.Event('keypress', {which: 13, keyCode: 13, charCode: 13});
    $searchbox.trigger(e);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="twotabsearchtextbox"/>
<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. So the keypress event is triggered by click (or other user's actions) it will submit the wrapping form, but if not it won't submit for security reason? I also confirmed it works in that way. https://jsfiddle.net/ctx0es1f/

Comment: "if not it won't submit for security reason?", my opinion is it not securit reason.

Comment: You can reference :[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_trigger.asp)